Vitest unable to find element with role='button' and aria-label despite it appearing in the DOM debug
I'm encountering an issue with Vitest where it cannot find an element with role="button" and aria-label matching /open notifications/i, even though the element appears clearly in the debug output:

Here's the relevant code for my test:
it.only('renders NotificationBadge with fetched notifications', async () => {
    renderWithTheme();

    await waitFor(() => {
      const openNotifications = screen.getByRole('button', {
        name: /open notifications/i
      });
      expect(openNotifications).toBeInTheDocument();
      expect(
        screen.getByLabelText(/unread notifications/i)
      ).toBeInTheDocument();

      fireEvent.click(openNotifications);

      expect(screen.getByText('Notifications')).toBeInTheDocument();
      const notifications = screen.getAllByText(
        /library for interacting with/i
      );

      expect(notifications).toHaveLength(8);
    });
  });


The element is definitely present in the DOM. Here's a screenshot from DevTools showing the element:

Why might Vitest not be able to find this element, despite it appearing in the DOM?
When I query with getByLabelText, it works, but I don’t understand why it doesn’t work with getByRole. The documentation states very clearly that it should.

Is showing up as an ignored node, because it's being ignored - it's in a div[aria-hidden="true"].

You’re right, my friend. I didn’t realize that having an element inside a hidden container would make all its child elements inaccessible. After your insight, I was able to discover it. Thank you!"

Now i don't understanding why the aria-hidden is true. That div is a simple div in my code, i didn't set aria-hidden at any moment. Any idea why is this happening?

Without a [mre] (don't include screenshots unless absolutely necessary), it's impossible to say.
